# Access ASP.Net rolesprovider from external assembly

Tags: asp.net

I have a RolesProvider properly registered and functioning. When the ASPX-page is executed I do some of the work in external assemblies (.dll-files referenced in, plain vanilla).

**I need to access methods on this role provider from the external assembly. How can I do that?**

Note: I don't want to pass a reference from ASPX to the external class if possible. Something like "HttpContext.Current.Roles" would be great.

Bonus: Shed some light on when and how is the custom ASP.Net RoleProvider used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just access the static `Roles` class which lives in the namespace `System.Web.Security`. Remember to add a reference to `System.Web.dll` as well in your external project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles(v=VS.100).aspx

*Manages user membership in roles for authorization checking in an ASP.NET application. This class cannot be inherited.*